# Wildfly: how to resolve VFS URL to physical URL?

Tags: java, url, wildfly, vfs

How to resolve Wildfly vfs URL to physical URL? e.g.

```
vfs:/C:/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/bin/content/foo.ear/myejb.jar/
```

The java code must not have dependency on Wildfly or other libraries.

Comment: VFS is used in Wildfly/JBoss in this case for something that resides within an archive file of some sort.  There is a physical location for this resource but it's not a filesystem physical location.  It's not clear what you're trying to get to.  If your code needs to start with `if(location.startsWith("vfs"))` then that still allows it to run in something besides Wildfly.

Comment: Thanks. How to resolve the VFS URI to a physical URI such as file:/ or jar:/ that exists on regular file system?

Comment: There is no `file://` conversion as the file you're looking for is embedded inside a `.jar` file.  There is no physical file - it's inside of the jar.  Regardless of the application server you will need to read the file out of the jar using something like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar).

Comment: We can read a file inside a jar URL (jar://). But is there a way to know the physical location for VFS so that we can do something with it?  Wildfly/Jboss should resolve VFS URL before passing it to an app or component. Otherwise it would create a dependency on Wildfly.